Node.js installation error. error code 2894
I'm using Windows 10 64-bit OS. It shows that the installer has encountered an unexpected error 2894. How can I fix this?
I've tried the steps:
Firstly,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wGhzTfLz2Q&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0
Secondly,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG2TEm9OQ-U&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0
Please ignore this,
Firstly,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\_wGhzTfLz2Q&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\_wGhzTfLz2Q&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0
Secondly,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG2TEm9OQ-U&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG2TEm9OQ-U&pp=ygU2VGhlIGluc3RhbGxlciBoYXMgZW5jb3VudGVyZWQgYW4gdW5leHBlY3RlZCBlcnJvciAyODk0

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the steps that you've tried as text in your question.  Please read why we ask that you not post text as images. That applies (even more so) to videos. Please do not expect readers to watch those videos in order to figure out what you've tried. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The 3rd and 4th link point to the same. The 5th and 6th link point to the same. The 3rd link is broken: "This video isn't available anymore"

This issue seems like it's an issue with the Windows Installer instead of Node.js particularly.

Open CMD and type msiexec and press Enter. That should open a window with Windows Installer information without any errors.

Open Services, go to Windows Installer and make sure it's set to Manual and not Disabled. Right-click it and Start the service, which should start without any issues.

Unregister and register the MSIExec engine. Open CMD and type
msiexec /unregister. Then type
msiexec /regserver.
No output will be received after typing the two commands.


